# Linq to Sql insert fail for inserting multiple rows from gridview to database

Tags: c#, gridview, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq to Sql for Database connection.I got 2 gridviews with `CheckBoxRowSelect`.The code below inserting just the last selected row,not all the records.My point was from first grid selecting 1 row from the second grid selecting 2 rows and i want to insert 2 times with first row value.Any suggestions?

```
LinqDataContext dtx=new LinqDataContext();    
YETKI kul = new YETKI();

int[] firmasec = gridView2.GetSelectedRows();
int[] kullanıcısec=gridView1.GetSelectedRows();

for (int a = 0; a < gridView1.SelectedRowsCount; a++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gridView2.SelectedRowsCount; i++)
    {
        kul.FIRMA_ROWID = int.Parse(gridView2.GetRowCellValue(firmasec[i], "ROWID").ToString());
        kul.KULLANICI_ROWID = int.Parse(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(kullanıcısec[a], "ROWID").ToString());
        kul.KULLANABILIR = 1;
    }
    dtx.YETKIs.FirstOrDefault();
    dtx.YETKIs.InsertOnSubmit(kul);
    dtx.SubmitChanges();
}
MessageBox.Show("Inserted!");
```

Comment: `My point was from first grid selecting 1 row from the second grid selecting 2`, you are doing `Insert` on outer loop, so it should only be done once, Move the `Insert` code to inner loop, if you want it to be executed for each iteration of inner loop.

Comment: I already tried it but if i move the submitChanges() metod in the loop it's firing fail and just inserting once.When loop comin for the second times it's fail.

Comment: You need to move object instantiation in inner loop as well , move this line `YETKI kul = new YETKI();` to inner loop.

Comment: This could also be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104952/add-multiple-record-using-linq-to-sql

Comment: It's firing invalid operation exception. It says something like "the object con not be added,it's already exist"

Comment: I thing it's ready with your solution. :))) Thank you very much @Habib